# MERN Deploy to heroku errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy an app using MERN, when I run the command "heroku create app_name" and push there, whenever I refresh a page (except '/') I receive Content Security Policy loading the favicon.

I've tried all the solutions I found, using meta tag, content-security-policy middleware but still nothing.

Then I found a solution from Mars using this command "heroku create app_name --buildpack mars/create-react-app" and it really worked, but all the POST requests are being rejected "405 Not Allowed"...

Any idea how to deploy a React app with Node JS to Heroku without having so many troubles? I've already spent almost a full day on it

back packate.json

```
{
    "name": "backend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "server:dev": "SET NODE_ENV=development & nodemon server.js",
        "server:prod": "node server.js",
        "start": "node server.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "cloudinary": "^1.18.1",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-fileupload": "^1.1.6",
        "express-session": "^1.17.0",
        "express-socket.io-session": "^1.3.5",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "mongodb": "^3.4.1",
        "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
    }
}
```

front package.json

```
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
        "react": "^16.12.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
        "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
        "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
        "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
        "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
        "sweetalert2": "^9.8.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

> ```
> 2020-03-17T12:56:45.207732+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.47a6fa91.chunk.js" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=7acc7bb3-1577-49f4-bc7e-4b8a807faa3b fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=40ms status=200 bytes=442167 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:56:45.824743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.f42a5d09.chunk.js" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=bd3764f5-0e43-4150-aafe-9eacf36b7153 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=51248 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:56:45.805711+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.a6a370ee.chunk.css" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=4d7aff67-9c04-46f3-bf8e-9ec8f2f29dd5 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=18094 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:56:46.400829+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=23dabc3f-443e-4b33-84f9-75bced9786b3 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=787 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:56:46.988497+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=61e3fc93-8a19-43ea-a279-07cde1086b94 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=5622 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:57:02.557237+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=bc28c6d9-1064-4d6b-ab9b-3d6aa9cdb589 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:57:03.076838+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.a6a370ee.chunk.css" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=b2bf1202-c6a5-4eee-885c-4c3a8600173d fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:57:03.085306+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.f42a5d09.chunk.js" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=247457a1-e70c-461c-bdae-3fa5641feeef fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:57:03.097918+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.47a6fa91.chunk.js" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=ac3fd8ac-ecf3-41c2-86c0-2c0e4f5d5db1 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=24ms status=200 bytes=442167 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:57:03.546592+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=7763b28e-180e-404f-85e6-90235c9fbfdb fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:57:04.111155+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=cc3b870a-9261-4e14-9121-dc5d671deb74 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:57:04.038020+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=75dcaabd-be40-45df-bbda-686bbb5a8952 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=5748 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:57:16.433412+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3eaT5i" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=4fc60d29-91b1-46af-a88f-f6ab0ae54135 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=322 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:57:17.362904+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3eaTML&sid=YEiDAM_hvzxUvrflAAAG" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=d4304608-7aae-4892-8489-273bf14254c2 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=226 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:57:20.106227+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3eaTXC&sid=YEiDAM_hvzxUvrflAAAG" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=678d3e53-dbeb-44fb-bb54-763b2b048b67 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2053ms status=200 bytes=225 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:58:05.765544+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/auth/register" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=de77674e-3fdd-4cbe-9151-57dee0ba535a fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1623ms status=200 bytes=545 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:58:06.438514+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/api/auth/sendOtp" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=eab712a7-b4cb-4091-b6e4-f4c2791d466b fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=404 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:58:14.164237+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/api/auth/verify" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=72f086df-2db6-47fb-a5d8-11aa2ae70fc9 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=403 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:58:20.744833+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/api/auth/verify" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=b30032ef-9f9c-45d0-a275-ad9af44165ad fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=403 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:58:53.717751+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/auth/logout" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=10cc9eae-a4bb-4b07-9e6a-3d57a94acdb1 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=7ms status=401 bytes=171 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:59:11.856199+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/auth/register" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=f5c967f1-f4b7-4437-b615-8fcb21eef62b fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1982ms status=200 bytes=545 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T12:59:12.153226+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/api/auth/sendOtp" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=b1b2a04e-ca7c-47d8-b0d1-27e5f1bc5e9b fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=404 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user user@gmail.com
> 2020-03-17T13:00:38.506854+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/auth/logout" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=18943d9b-67db-4b9a-978c-d8076a1983ec fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=401 bytes=171 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:38.669416+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=90100281-0d3b-4036-a06a-a584e4cb8ef1 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:38.939228+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.a6a370ee.chunk.css" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=2a405c7c-2d30-45e5-94c9-ed2b1f5bf469 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:38.948360+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.47a6fa91.chunk.js" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=5bde332f-9e1f-4c5e-9f93-e9881753335d fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:38.928428+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=IjkOIpWfVhGC_4GeAAAD" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=74d19e52-362a-4298-9608-2de3210ed555 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=453676ms status=101 bytes=234 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:39.223414+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.47a6fa91.chunk.js.map" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=ee780327-3597-4ae6-ab94-dc635de553d9 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=240 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:39.064267+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.f42a5d09.chunk.js" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=0ffadaa3-b2df-43c9-bd7b-d3769ad8a696 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:39.217788+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.a6a370ee.chunk.css.map" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=bd9858b1-b42f-48f6-8cd8-055978d4730a fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:39.328000+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ebFVH" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=6f8c5762-57f1-4939-8147-80cb77e6ebc6 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=322 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:39.418033+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.f42a5d09.chunk.js.map" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=cb54ac75-4d2b-41f8-8d0a-2378c9c03e89 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:39.512338+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=2912c9fe-f484-4fd3-85be-90bb170baaf8 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=41174 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:39.580665+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ebFZD&sid=6f-3LJx72SMiMzvNAAAH" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=ab4ade45-346e-45d8-b0ee-9a0639d4d85d fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=226 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:40.230503+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=c3a0abd6-4c79-424a-9e8f-854a5ee4ffc7 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=363 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:40.479351+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=9f9b31ce-cbfa-4c53-bc9c-1976f157272e fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:40.431391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ebFdD&sid=6f-3LJx72SMiMzvNAAAH" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=c3d3ef3a-a9b1-49f1-b15b-56afbc8ff585 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=599ms status=200 bytes=225
> protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:49.028336+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=6f-3LJx72SMiMzvNAAAH" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=2df013ef-9a9a-4e56-ad01-4699ede9e0bb fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8952ms status=101 bytes=183 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:55.249346+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
> 2020-03-17T13:00:55.265581+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
> 2020-03-17T13:00:54.914448+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user user@gmail.com
> 2020-03-17T13:00:56.174252+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
> 2020-03-17T13:00:56.192941+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=YEiDAM_hvzxUvrflAAAG" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=a422ba78-068d-46f2-b489-10a6a4a796a7 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=217194ms status=101 bytes=175 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:56.191288+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=ef7NAQ1wZdUwukX-AAAF" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=b656622d-2aa6-420c-9490-09c8cdc79991 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=269182ms status=101 bytes=175 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:56.193307+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=VLVQa2k7ctohGmtIAAAE" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=4829647b-a05d-4465-b82e-6e3bc52d75c7 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=408245ms status=101 bytes=175 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:00:56.252495+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
> 2020-03-17T13:00:54.914448+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 56f49592 by user user@gmail.com
> 2020-03-17T13:00:57.993781+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
> 2020-03-17T13:00:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
> 2020-03-17T13:01:00.690682+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 2020-03-17T13:01:00.690702+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start /app
> 2020-03-17T13:01:00.690702+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
> 2020-03-17T13:01:00.690703+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 2020-03-17T13:01:01.306960+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
> 2020-03-17T13:01:01.306967+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
> 2020-03-17T13:01:01.306967+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
> 2020-03-17T13:01:01.314922+00:00 app[web.1]: Server is running on port: 42579
> 2020-03-17T13:01:02.332119+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
> 2020-03-17T13:01:02.629113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ebJBo" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=cf695255-6438-430f-b5d3-edeec23236ef fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=322 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:01:02.927068+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ebKQm&sid=0gJyzxdgmCv3fvisAAAA" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=fed77ca7-6bb2-4db3-8c81-325558114b7b fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=226 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:01:03.330739+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ebK0c" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=b4666db4-515f-4e47-9410-093511db9b23 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=322 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:01:03.573888+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ebLQ9&sid=zNi13ZfR3OhHqbBTAAAB" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=1c44b3c7-6349-468b-81c1-6adcfdc9897c fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=226 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:01:03.942367+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ebKVg&sid=0gJyzxdgmCv3fvisAAAA" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=ab672e41-f339-49a2-af2b-b2a2a01dc11c fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=685ms status=200 bytes=225 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:01:04.108685+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ebJCX" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=932f8fb4-ec01-4456-8af0-c7d6b4c5e9db fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=322 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:01:04.369835+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ebLT-&sid=zNi13ZfR3OhHqbBTAAAB" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=a69e7fc1-a087-440d-8ace-a604e32dfea0 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=548ms status=200 bytes=225
> protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:01:04.566605+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ebKqV&sid=S9KM6nACbRWk4vOsAAAC" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=8916c9f9-38ed-4e3f-abad-a30ebea14471 fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=226 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:01:08.572823+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ebKv1&sid=S9KM6nACbRWk4vOsAAAC" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=65a75a96-4369-469b-af35-0a14e66e849b fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=3712ms status=200 bytes=225 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:01:39.160396+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=S9KM6nACbRWk4vOsAAAC" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=65d8fc36-8137-42e8-9d7b-a44cbb285fec fwd="109.253.162.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30969ms status=101 bytes=175 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:04:48.448660+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=zNi13ZfR3OhHqbBTAAAB" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=aa6c9023-4c8a-4da9-aeb0-663782f53efa fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=224420ms status=101 bytes=175 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:04:49.009673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=353051e7-861f-4317-9230-1c0bbbd11860 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=2766 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:04:49.260407+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.1061875e.chunk.js" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=c4df8bac-8b7a-4be4-8cf6-018cebe5ea64 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=51240 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:04:49.701644+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.a6a370ee.chunk.css" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=015488cb-2620-4cff-ac92-e18dab88fdcc fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=18094 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:04:49.736169+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.47a6fa91.chunk.js" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=47669af1-3c6d-4535-990c-10b1ca78d216 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=33ms status=200 bytes=442167 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:04:51.288521+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ecD0C" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=63100972-627a-4d1d-b983-ffedc58611d4 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=322 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:04:51.413285+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.a6a370ee.chunk.css.map" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=71113f66-f0da-4d21-b6b5-84e7954c90d9 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=49878 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:04:51.516886+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ecD3k&sid=x1ip-VgRSdk8qNz0AAAD" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=83ac129b-4749-4d39-91f1-291698bd8f6d fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=226 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:04:52.294569+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3ecD7O&sid=x1ip-VgRSdk8qNz0AAAD" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=745ce364-c016-4ea1-99ec-cdf0feb17432 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=550ms status=200 bytes=225
> protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:05:04.715275+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
> 2020-03-17T13:05:07.636714+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/auth/register" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=f1219d24-2656-4499-9f83-c9e4a6f0e51a fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2990ms status=200 bytes=550 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:05:07.838674+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/auth/sendOtp" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=50fa6626-9101-4259-befe-8d67b9b3188b fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=401 bytes=171 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:07:47.704741+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/auth/sendOtp" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=f9c481b1-1402-41b7-8cfc-3027ec666e8d fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=401 bytes=171 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:11:42.192377+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/auth/logout" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=da132660-1ff7-4642-9b0b-5610af4e7977 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=401 bytes=171 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:11:43.548766+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=x1ip-VgRSdk8qNz0AAAD" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=da959a45-1418-4c50-986a-c32ddf7de6c1 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=411581ms status=101 bytes=175 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:11:43.579968+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=07a659a0-7d5a-4efc-a5b7-43155667f019 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:11:43.776501+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.47a6fa91.chunk.js" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=d102e834-2d26-4875-8707-59fd6beeb0ae fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:11:44.116258+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.1061875e.chunk.js" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=10e3de75-9e95-4f8b-bd3d-e682437382a8 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:11:44.083654+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.a6a370ee.chunk.css" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=72d749e1-a61d-4a75-ab37-d992f433df5c fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:11:45.231288+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3edo4C" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=2f177664-0673-4aa4-a651-daa3b9a57992 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=322 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:11:45.331528+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.a6a370ee.chunk.css.map" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=2de32c10-9c56-4489-b60e-879b53303e5e fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:11:45.397229+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3edo6n&sid=3TIEbTwhFHQGtpNAAAAE" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=fa892ae9-c23f-4235-8303-08c198a3be43 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=226 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:11:46.000975+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3edo9O&sid=3TIEbTwhFHQGtpNAAAAE" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=146b72b8-e66f-4d64-b654-819e50f1790f fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=438ms status=200 bytes=225
> protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:12:00.945917+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/auth/register" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=559ef3dc-5cec-4d15-bea4-37bd91ce302a fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1411ms status=200 bytes=541 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:12:01.123848+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/auth/sendOtp" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=9c5a5042-b1d4-4e35-baa1-e9314e84ff03 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=401 bytes=171 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:12:39.077838+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.1061875e.chunk.js.map" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=d14330b0-a93a-43f4-ac56-faad8160f1ac fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=113350 protocol=https
> 2020-03-17T13:12:39.129458+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.47a6fa91.chunk.js.map" host=appointmentsmanager.herokuapp.com request_id=5c914e54-1700-4219-bf83-1c6372cb7008 fwd="93.173.124.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=53ms status=200 bytes=1514774 protocol=https
> ```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const sharedsession = require('express-socket.io-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

const authRoutes = require('./api/auth/auth-routes');
const userRoutes = require('./api/user/user-routes');
const calendarRoutes = require('./api/calendar/calendar-routes');
const smsRoutes = require('./api/sms/sms-routes');

const connectedSockets = require('./api/sockets/socket-routes');

const session = require("express-session")({
    secret: 'my-secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
});

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session)
app.use(fileUpload({
    limits: { fileSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024 },
    useTempFiles: true,
    tempFileFir: '/temp/'
}));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const corsOptions = {
        origin: ['http://127.0.0.1:3000', 'http://localhost:3000'],
        credentials: true
    };
    app.use(cors(corsOptions));
}

app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/user', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/calendar', calendarRoutes);
app.use('/api/sms', smsRoutes);
io.use(sharedsession(session));
connectedSockets(io);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('build'));
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port: ' + port);
})
```

Folder structure

[image]

Comment: Without an error traceback we cannot tell what's wrong. Without a general log we cannot tell how far your program has made it without failing. You did not say what you've exactly done so far e.g. port binding which is a very common error. You have not shown how you are executing `npm install and npm run build` on heroku to ensure the files are build properly. There is no `package.json` no `Procfile` etc in your question. A badly formulated question will not get receive helpful answers because they just can't give you a proper answer.

Comment: @Tin Nguyen Well I was asking for a general help how to deploy MERN project, but I added some info. Currently heroku is running without Mars buildpacks

Comment: There is not much general advice one can give. The edit was more helpful but it is still lacking information.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process `heroku-postbuild` is missing. Folder structure about where the `package.json` are located is also important. Heroku does not scan your every folder for a `package.json` you need to point to it. Did you version your `build` folder?

Comment: @Tin Nguyen I tried to add to heroku post build but couldn't deploy, it returns an error ng not found, I added more info

Comment: You have to adjust the postbuild script to your need. I suggest you deploy a minimum example MERN stack first before proceeding further: https://github.com/accimeesterlin/mern-stack-deploy-heroku